# Crystal Report: Display Text according to Array Index on Different Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

all

Say I have a dynamically generated array containing strings:  {Tom, Bill, Jane, Lucy, Jam}
   I would like to have Tom shows in page 1 header, Bill shows in page 2 header, Jane shows in page 3 header, etc.

The idea is to achieve the " assign to " feature, which essentially building only one crystal report, but different pages are delivered to different person so that the person who get the one page of the report has his/her name on it.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: provide more info like how do u get data, how do you use this array inside the report( as parameter or datasource), what if no.of pages exceed no. of elements in the array.....

Comment: hi, Deb. I am thinking about using the array as parameter. But I have no certain idea if it is applicable. So it would be welcome to provide any suggestion.

Comment: Why not make those names parts of your datasource then you will be able to grouping and at the end of each group you can specify a page break. Otherwise you can pass the names as CSV string and write a formula toconvert them into an array and if pageno<elemnts of array then retun the matching name. This formula you can later use it at page header.

Comment: How are you generating the report?  BusinessObjects Enterprise (if so, which version), manually using Crystal Reports, or a custom application (which you have access to the source code)?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called 'report bursting'.  There are two types of bursting: single-pass and multi-pass.

With single-pass bursting:

- the report is generated once
- a record-selection formula is applied for each recipient

With multi-pass bursting:

- the report is generated once for each recipient, where the recipient ID is parameterized.

BusinessObjects Enterprise XI supports both approaches using a Publication.  The recipients can be BO users or 'external' (Publications use Crystal Reports or WebI reports for this, strangely enough) recipients.  You can deliver the reports to BO Inboxes or SMTP inboxes (among others) in a variety of formats.

If you don't have BO, you might want to consider Apos' Bursting Manager.

If you have programming expertise, you can easily burst a report using the Crystal Reports SDK.  You store the original record-selection formula, append a WHERE clause snippet to it that will filter the report (for a recipient, for example), deliver the report in the desired format, restore the original RSF, then repeat.